# Prove that if G is connected then v $\in$ V(G) has a neighbor in every component of G-v

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I understand what the question is asking but am not sure how to begin the proof. G-v is the set of vertices and edges which are in G but not v

Comment: it follows directly from the definition of connected graph. Think of what will happen if v did not have a neighbour in any component of G-v.

Comment: Can you expand further on this? What would happen if v did not have a neighbour in any component of G-v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path-components of $G-v$ do not have neighbours between them i.e if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are any two path-components of $G-v$, there is no edge from a vertex in $G_1$ to a vertex in $G_2$ (this is by definition of path-component). So the only way the original graph would be connected is there is a path from $G_1$ to $G_2$ through $v$.

Note that if $G-v$ is just one component, then $G$ is connected.